The result of an onClick function appearing only after reloading the app (React.js)
I'm making my first react app, a to-do list. Everything seems quite fine, the only problem I have is that the delete and complete buttons only work after refreshing a page. Well, actually they work pretty well and as they should (I mean, I can see the console.log results in the console after clicking a button), but the front-end results I can only see after refreshing my app. I really don't know what's going on. Here's the code (it's pretty long, but I don't know where the issue lies, so I'm showing all of it):
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { Trash, Check } from "@phosphor-icons/react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000";

function App() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('ToDoTab');
  const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("");
  const [inputDescription, setInputDescription] = useState("");
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [completedTasks, setCompletedTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resp = axios.get("/todos").then((resp) => {
      setTasks(resp.data);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const completedResp = axios.get("/completedTodos").then((completedResp) => {
      setCompletedTasks(completedResp.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleTabClick = (tabId) => {
    setActiveTab(tabId);
  };

  async function addTask(e) {
    const data = {
      name: inputName,
      desc: inputDescription,
      status: "false",
    }
    const resp = await axios.post("/todos", data);
    if (resp.data.success) {
      setTasks((prevTasks) => [...prevTasks, resp.data.newTask.rows[0]]);
    }
    setInputName("");
    setInputDescription("");
  };

  async function completeTask(e, todo) {
    const resp = await axios.put(`/todos/${todo.taskID}`);
    if (resp.data.success) {
      setTasks(prevTasks => prevTasks.filter(t => t.taskID !== todo.taskID));
    }
  };

  async function deleteTask(e, todo) {
    const resp = await axios.delete(`/todos/${todo.taskID}`);
    if (resp.data.success) {
      setTasks(prevTasks => prevTasks.filter(t => t.taskID !== todo.taskID));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="background">
      <header className="todos-header">
        <p className="header-text">My Todos</p>
        <div className="box">

          {/* Form */}
          <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
            <table className="table-one">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th><label htmlFor="title">Title:</label></th>
                  <th><label htmlFor="info">Description:</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input
                    type="text"
                    id="title"
                    name="title"
                    placeholder={inputName ? "" : "What's the title of your To Do?"}
                    value={inputName}
                    onChange={(e) => setInputName(e.target.value)}></input></td>
                  <td><input
                    type="text"
                    id="info"
                    name="info"
                    placeholder={inputDescription ? "" : "What's the title of your To Do?"}
                    value={inputDescription}
                    onChange={(e) => setInputDescription(e.target.value)}></input></td>
                  <td><button
                    type="button"
                    className="add-button"
                    onClick={addTask}>Add</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>

          <div className="tasks">
            <button
              onClick={() => handleTabClick('ToDoTab')}
              style={{ backgroundColor: activeTab === 'ToDoTab' ? '#02e77e' : '#5c5c5c' }}>To Do</button>
            <button
              onClick={() => handleTabClick('CompletedTab')}
              style={{ backgroundColor: activeTab === 'CompletedTab' ? '#02e77e' : '#5c5c5c' }}>Completed</button>

            {/* To Do boxes */}
            <div className="tasks-holder" id="ToDoTab" style={{ display: activeTab === 'ToDoTab' ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
              {tasks.map((todo, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="tasks-box" key={todo.taskID}>
                    <table className="table-two">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <h1>{todo.name}</h1>
                            <p>{todo.description}</p>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <Trash className="icon-space trash" size={40} color="#fff" onClick={(e) => deleteTask(e, todo)} />
                            <Check className="icon-space check" size={40} color="#02e77e" onClick={(e) => completeTask(e, todo)} />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>

            {/* Completed boxes */}
            <div className="tasks-holder" id="CompletedTab" style={{ display: activeTab === 'CompletedTab' ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
              {completedTasks.map((todo, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="tasks-box" key={todo.taskID}>
                    <table className="table-two">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <h1>{todo.name}</h1>
                            <p>{todo.description}</p>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <Trash className="icon-space trash" size={40} color="#fff" style={{marginLeft: '20px'}} onClick={(e) => deleteTask(e, todo)} />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Everything on the back-end seems fine. I've already checked if there are any issues on the server, but it's not delaying anything, I think it works just as it should. I've also tried triggering the rerendering but it doesn't work as well and there are no errors in the console.

Why did you put e.preventDefault() in onSubmit method? Just check that once

@Pranav I've tried removing it but it still doesn't work as it should.

Make sure that in the responses you get the correct value in resp.data.success. Judging by the behavior of the application, there is no update to the state of the component
